# Abstract language for code generation java and c

Tags: java, c, code-generation

I'm working on a native android application which has both `.c` and `.java` code. And sometimes I want to use the same emumerations so I have both

on native side

```
enum _enum_1 {
    VALUE_1 = 0,
    VALUE_2 = 1
};

typedef enum _enum_1 enum_1;
```

on java side

```
public enum Enum1 {
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2
}
```

My question is, is there an abstract language to describe enums/classes/structs which can be used to generate a code for `java` and `c` languages?

Comment: Please correct the typo in ` VALUE_2 = 0, VALUE_2 = 1`

Comment: You can do this using the C preprocessor. (I have done it for generating code for C and another HLL that is similar to Pascal.) There will be limitations - I don't think that a C union can be expressed (semantically truly equivalent) in Java.

Comment: You could use reelection on the java code to write the C.

Comment: @WW. That's not a well-known term - do you have and pointers, please?

Comment: @laune They mean to say reflection.

Comment: You might put your enum declarations in some XML and then apply different XSLT transformations to generate Java, C, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASN.1 (Abstract Syntax Notation One) is one quite ofter used abstract language. 
The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) contains links to different java and C generators for ASN.1 .

There quite big list of similar interface description language listed in [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language).